# Skyrim thieves guild influence jobs glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have completed the thieves guild main story, I returned the key and everything, but I want to fully complete it. So I go back to the guild and try to take influence jobs to eventually become guild master, but I completed one numbers job for Delvin in Whiterun and turned it in, but now it won't give me any more job quests. I talk to both Delvin and Vex and go through the dialogue where they say here's your quest but it doesn't come up in my journal at all, and it's like i didn't ask them... someone please help with this bug? I am a completionist and this is bugging me. pun intended.

Comment: I think that this is in fact a duplicate, it is a common issue that these jobs will target a non-essential character that could have been killed previously, which leads to the bug. AFAIK there is no fix but to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might have bugged out, did it to me with the stormcloak quests. Try reloading from a save before you took the first job and try again

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug that usually strikes when Windhelm is the target hold. There's no getting around it, you'll need to reload a save.  You can, however, prevent it.

1. Refuse quests that send you to the bugged hold.  Do all of your Delvin and Vex jobs in other holds, but cancel them if they send you to that hold.
2. Complete the quest for a different hold.  Save.
3. See if you can do the affected hold now.

The cause is somewhat random, if the above works.  There's another potential problem which can occur. In my case, it was because a contact NPC was killed 
 by a dragon before they were set essential by the quest.  The TG quests are riddled with bugs like this; it pays off to spoil yourself a little and use the console to set to essential anyone who might break a quest if they are dead.